# SmartView SDK Samsung / Tizen - Internal Server Error 500

Tags: ios, swift, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

Has anyone used Samsung/Tizen SDK for iOS.
https://github.com/SamsungDForum/SmartViewSDKCastVideo

I have been using it and it worked perfect. Since yesterday when I try to connect to my TV. It generates this error. I have downloaded several sample codes from their git portal and each has the same issue. Can someone please assist. Thanks.

> Optional(Error Domain=HTTP Request Code=500 "Internal Server Error"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Internal Server Error})
>   Optional("Internal Server Error")

```
func launchApplicationTv(service:Service, completionHandler: (isTVConnected:Bool) -> () )
    {
        self.serviceSearch.stop()
        self.serviceSearch.stopUsingBLE()
        self.stoplisteningForNotifications()

        let appID = kSAMSUNG_APPID
        let channelID = kSAMSUNG_CHANNELID

        print("input: createApplication:(appId):\(appID) channelURI: \(channelID)  args: %@")

        self.samsung_app = service.createApplication(kSAMSUNG_APPID, channelURI: kSAMSUNG_CHANNELID, args: nil)

        self.samsung_app.delegate = self;
        self.samsung_app.connectionTimeout = 100.0


        let dict:NSDictionary = ["name":kiOS_DEVICE]

        self.samsung_app.start({ (success,error) -> Void in
            if success
            {
                self.samsung_app.connect((dict as! [String : String]), completionHandler: ({ (ChannelClient,error) -> Void in
                    print("Connected")
                    self.connectedService = service;
                    completionHandler(isTVConnected: true)
                }))
            }
            else
            {
                completionHandler(isTVConnected: false)

                print("Couldn't Connect")
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                {
                    self.showError()
                })

                self.terminateConnection()
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is finally solved. I got a reply from Samsung Development Team.

> Sorry,
>
> iOS lib is updated 2.3.1
>
> plz, download new version
>
> https://www.samsungdforum.com/AddLibrary/SmartViewDownload

Release Notes on Samsung Development SDK Download Page

> Unexpected error occured in '15 TVs from firmware update (ver 1460.xx)
>   that iOS and JavaScript API does NOT find and connect to the TVs.  The
>   libraries to fix the issue have updated from 2016/08/01. Please
>   download and update the library with the new one.  We apologize for
>   any inconvenience caused to your service.